# Determine $x+y$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $(2x+1)^2+y^2+(y-2x)^2=\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, real-numbers

Determine $x+y$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $(2x+1)^2+y^2+(y-2x)^2=\frac{1}{3}$
I used the quadratic equation to get $$x=\frac{y-1\pm\sqrt{-2y-3y^2-\frac{5}{3}}}{4}$$

But I don’t see how that helps, hints and solutions would be appreciated

Taken from the 2006 IWYMIC

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that $\frac{1}{3}$ is the unique minimum of the function $f(x,y)=(2x+1)^2+y^2+(y-2x)^2$. Then find the $(x,y)$ where this minimum occurs.

Your expression under the radical is also incorrect. It should be $-3y^2-2y-\frac{1}{3}$, or $-\frac{1}{3}(9y^2+6y+1) = -\frac{1}{3}(3y+1)^2$. Thus there is exactly one value of $y$ for which the expression under the radical is nonnegative.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. $-\frac{1}{3}(9y^2+6y+1) = -\frac{1}{3}(3y+1)^2$ not $-\frac{1}{3}(2y+1)^2$

Comment: Thanks, typo corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply out and collect terms $$8x^2+4x-4xy+2y^2+\frac{2}{3}=0.$$

Multiply by $6$ and complete the square for $x$ terms $$3(4x+1-y)^2+9y^2+6y+1=0$$
$$3(4x+1-y)^2+(3y+1)^2=0$$
Therefore $x=y=-\frac{1}{3}.$